# In R: Split a character vector to find specific characters and return a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, split, strsplit

I want to be able to extract specific characters from a character vector in a data frame and return a new data frame. The information I want to extract is auditors remark on a specific company's income and balance sheet. My problem is that the auditors remarks are stored in vectors containing the different remarks. For instance:

`vec = c("A C G H D E")`. Since `"A" %in% vec` won't return `TRUE`, I have to use `strsplit` to break up each character vector in the data frame, hence `"A" %in% unlist(strsplit(dat[i, 2], " ")`. This returns `TRUE`.

Here is a MWE:

```
dat <- data.frame(orgnr = c(1, 2, 3, 4), rat = as.character(c("A B C")))
dat$rat <- as.character(dat$rat)
dat[2, 2] <- as.character(c("A F H L H"))
dat[3, 2] <- as.character(c("H X L O"))
dat[4, 2] <- as.character(c("X Y Z A B C"))
```

Now, to extract information about every single letter in the `rat` coloumn, I've tried several approaches, following similar problems such as Roland's answer to a similar question ([How to split a character vector into data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22455884/how-to-split-a-character-vector-into-data-frame))

```
DF <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(dat$rat, " ", fixed = TRUE)))
DF
   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6
1  A  B  C  A  B  C
2  A  F  H  L  H  A
3  H  X  L  O  H  X
4  X  Y  Z  A  B  C
```

This returnsthe following error message: `Warning message:
In (function (..., deparse.level = 1)  :
  number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)`

It would be a desirable approach since it's fast, but I can't use `DF` since it recycles.
**Is there a way to insert `NA` instead of the recycling because of the different length of the vectors?**

So far I've found a solution to the problem by using for-loops in combination with `ifelse`-statements. However, with 3 mill obs. this approach takes years!

```
dat$A <- 0

for(i in seq(1, nrow(dat), 1)) {
  print(i)
  dat[i, 3] <- ifelse("A" %in% unlist(strsplit(dat[i, 2], " ")), 1, 0)
}

dat$B <- 0

for(i in seq(1, nrow(dat), 1)) {
  print(i)
  dat[i, 4] <- ifelse("B" %in% unlist(strsplit(dat[i, 2], " ")), 1, 0)
}
```

This gives the results I want:

```
dat
  orgnr         rat A B
1     1       A B C 1 1
2     2   A F H L H 1 0
3     3     H X L O 0 0
4     4 X Y Z A B C 1 1
```

I've searched through most of the relevant questions I could find here on StackOverflow. This one is really close to my problem: [How to convert a list consisting of vector of different lengths to a usable data frame in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201305/how-to-convert-a-list-consisting-of-vector-of-different-lengths-to-a-usable-data), but I don't know how to implement `strsplit` with that approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use for-loop with `grepl` to achieve this task. `+ 0` is to convert the column form `TRUE` or `FALSE` to 1 or 0

```
for (col in c("A", "B")){
  dat[[col]] <- grepl(col, dat$rat) + 0
}
dat
#   orgnr         rat A B
# 1     1       A B C 1 1
# 2     2   A F H L H 1 0
# 3     3     H X L O 0 0
# 4     4 X Y Z A B C 1 1
```

If performance is an issue, try this `data.table` approach.

```
library(data.table)

# Convert to data.table
setDT(dat)

# Create a helper function
dummy_fun <- function(col, vec){
  grepl(col, vec) + 0
}

# Apply the function to A and B
dat[, c("A", "B") := lapply(c("A", "B"), dummy_fun, vec = rat)] 
dat
#    orgnr         rat A B
# 1:     1       A B C 1 1
# 2:     2   A F H L H 1 0
# 3:     3     H X L O 0 0
# 4:     4 X Y Z A B C 1 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast respons, @WWW!

When I'm trying to run your solution using the data.table approach, I get the following warning message:

Warning messages:
1: In grepl(col, vec) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Instead of using c("A", "B") I use a vector with all the different letters there are in (19 different letters). Do you know how to overcome this problem?

(I also get the error message that the size is too big, "cannot allocate vector", but that is expected. I will try on a more powerfull computer later).

Comment: Not sure why you got the first error message. If you apply the `dummy_fun` to each string on by one using `lapply`, you should have only one pattern at a time.

Comment: Somehow your approach didn't work when I applied a stored vector of letters (vec). I had to put in all the letters the way you did in your example. Also, using the data table approach was extremely fast on over 3 mill observation. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

using Base R:

```
a=strsplit(dat$rat," ")
b=data.frame(x=rep(dat$orgnr,lengths(a)),y=unlist(a),z=1)
cbind(dat,as.data.frame.matrix(xtabs(z~x+y,b)))
  orgnr         rat A B C F H L O X Y Z
1     1       A B C 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
2     2   A F H L H 1 0 0 1 2 1 0 0 0 0
3     3     H X L O 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0
4     4 X Y Z A B C 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
```

From here you can Just call those columns that you want:

```
d=as.data.frame.matrix(xtabs(z~x+y,b))
 cbind(dat,d[c("A","B")])
  orgnr         rat A B
1     1       A B C 1 1
2     2   A F H L H 1 0
3     3     H X L O 0 0
4     4 X Y Z A B C 1 1
```