# [R]Split a character vector into data frame rows by set number of columns

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, multiple-columns

I can't seem to find this specifically (I looked here: [How to split a character vector into data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22455884/how-to-split-a-character-vector-into-data-frame)) and a few other places.

I am trying to split a character vector in R into a data frame, with a set number of columns, filling in NA for any extras or missing. As below (reproducible):

```
###Reproduce column vector
cv <- c("a1", "b1", "c1", "d1", "e1", "f1", "aa2", "bb2", "cc2", "dd2", "ee2", "ff2", "x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5", "x6", "rr2", "tt3", "bb4")

###Desired data frame separating 6 columns
df.desired <- data.frame(col1=c("a1","aa2","x1","rr2"),col2=c("b1","bb2","x2","tt3"),col3=c("c1","cc2","x3","bb4"),col4=c("d1","dd2","x4",NA),col5=c("e1","ee2","x5",NA),col6=c("f1","ff2","x6",NA),stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please be more explicit about the rule for allocating `NA` to different columns. Cheers

Answer (score 4):

**1) base** Create a matrix of NA values of the requisite dimensions and then fill it with `cv` up to its length.  Transpose that and convert to a data frame.

```
mat <- t(replace(matrix(NA, 6, ceiling(length(cv) / 6)), seq_along(cv), cv))
as.data.frame(mat, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

**2) another base solution**  Using the `cv2` copy of `cv` expand its length to that required and then reshape it into a matrix.  We used `cv2` in order to preserve the original `cv` but if you don't mind adding NAs to the end of `cv` then you could just use it instead of creating `cv2` reducing the code by one line (two lines if we can use `mat` rather than needing a data frame).  This solution avoids needing to use transpose by making use of the `byrow` argument of `matrix`.

```
cv2 <- cv
length(cv2) <- 6 * ceiling(length(cv) / 6)
mat <- matrix(cv2,, 6, byrow = TRUE)
as.data.frame(mat, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

**3) base solution using ts**   This one gets the row and column indexes by extracting them from the times of a `ts` object rather than calculating the dimensions via numeric calculation.   To do that create the times, `tt`, of a `ts` object from `cv`.  `tt` itself is a `ts` object for which `as.integer(tt)` is the row index numbers and `cycle(tt)` is the column index numbers.  Finally use `tapply` with that:

```
tt <- time(ts(cv, frequency = 6))
mat <- tapply(cv, list(as.integer(tt), cycle(tt)), c)
as.data.frame(mat, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

**4) rollapply** Like (3) this one does not explicitly calculate the dimensions of `mat`.  It uses `rollapply` in the zoo package with a simple function, `Fill`r to avoid this.  The `Fill` function returns its argument `x` padded out with NAs on the right to a length of 6.

```
library(zoo)

Fill <- function(x) { length(x) <- 6; x }
mat <- rollapplyr(cv, 6, by = 6, Fill, align = "left", partial = TRUE)
as.data.frame(mat, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

In all alternatives above omit the last line if a matrix `mat` is adequate as the result.

### Added

As of R 4.0 `stringsAsFaactors=FALSE` is the default so it could be omitted above.

Answer (score 1):

**1) base R** - `split` the `vector` using a grouping variable created with `gl` and then append `NA` at the end with `length<-`

```
lst <- split(cv, as.integer(gl(length(cv), 6, length(cv))))
as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(lst, `length<-`, max(lengths(lst)))))
#  V1  V2  V3   V4   V5   V6
#1  a1  b1  c1   d1   e1   f1
#2 aa2 bb2 cc2  dd2  ee2  ff2
#3  x1  x2  x3   x4   x5   x6
#4 rr2 tt3 bb4 <NA> <NA> <NA>
```